# ADF Update the record if column not matched (in 2nd condition)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am beginner in adf and trying to update SQL table through adf in Dataflw activity,

Source - Excel file
Sink - SQL table

Source and SinkColumns - AccountID, LegacyAccID, AccountGroupCD

Now I only want update the record in sink if below condition matched

**if(FileAccountID == DBLegacyID && FileAccountID != DBAccountID)**

I can map the FileAccountID == DBLegacyID in sink mapping , How can I add 2nd condition,
really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Alter Row transformation and set that conditional expression in the rule for the Update property.

Answer (score 0):

One quick thing which I can think , is to use the stored proc actvity on the sink side ( Since you have only few incoming columns ) and use the Update logic in the stored procedure .
HTH